# How to instruct JVM to lock all jar files used

Tags: java, linux, java-17

I have written a small app in Java. When it is running, the JAR file it runs from is not locked in any way and I can easily replace the JAR file with a new one. That leads to a lot of errors like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Is there a way to instruct OpenJDK to lock the JAR files it uses so that this problem cannot happen accidentally ?

Comment: Ermm ... why are you / is something changing the JAR file?

Comment: By mistake. I understand I should not do it, but locking the file (like the JDK does on Windows) prevents me and others from doing this mistake.

Comment: As far as I know, Linux has no mandatory file locking—at least in common configurations. As you note yourself, Java does lock the jar files, which will be mandatory under Windows.

Comment: So ... based on what Holger said, your best option is to ... just not modify the JAR files.  Or set the file permissions to make them not writable.

Comment: More practically: Copy the JAR file that might be modified to a different location before starting Java. Then you can modify the source all you want.